# Visual Studio & Windows - Stop Mouseover Fly outs for menus, sub-menus & Tool windows

Tags: visual-studio, mouseover, flyout

This is really driving me crazy !!

I am sure many developers out there love this feature, when tool tabs come darting out on mouseovers, like a jack russell on a double espresso, but it drives me insane.

I am partially signted and frequently have to locate my mouse pointer by shaking the mouse to move the pointer to a particular corner or side of the screen, so having things flyout all over the place, especially when some tools have to waste more time painting themsleves, makes me wanna scream.

If anyone knows how to turn this off, I would be gratefull and it would be even better if I could disable it for all of windows.

My thinking is that, if I wanna see something I will click and when I am done with it I will click away, is that really so hard.

Many thanks in advance

### UPDATE

So I figured out that this is a Windows-wide delay setting for mouse over, menu behaviour
specified in the registry in number of milliseconds

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\MenuShowDelay.

Mine was set to 8, and is the reason my menus were so frantic.

I changed this to the maximum allowable value of 65534 and no all my menus, submenus and tool windows only come out when I click them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out that this is a Windows-wide delay setting for mouse over, menu behaviour specified in the registry in number of milliseconds

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\MenuShowDelay.
```

Mine was set to 8, and is the reason my menus were so frantic.

I changed this to the maximum allowable value of 65534 and no all my menus, submenus and tool windows only come out when I click them

Answer (score 0):

I typically turn those default tabbed tools off. (close the windows)  But I think the option you are looking for is Tools > Options > Environment > General > "Animate Environment Tools".

Comment: Thank you, I am using VS 2010 Ultimate and cannot find this option Tools > Options > Environment > General

Comment: It seems there is no way to completely disable this in VS 2010. The only related options are those under Tools > Options > General > Visual Experienc, but none of them disables this behaviour. I thknk ithis is an oever signt, by simply assuming developers will want things to fly out if the computers hardware can support it